# Como puedo modificar y optimizar mi codigo para que el Navbar que estoy creado pueda ser agregado a todas las pantallas

Tags: api, flutter, dart, navbar, widget

estoy haciendo un navbar, he buscado varias formas de hacerlo con el gestor de estado GX me llego a sulucionar una parte, puedo agregarlo en todas las pantallas de esta maners

> class CustomBottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
> CustomBottomBar({super.key, this.onChanged});
>
> ```
>   RxInt selectedIndex = 0.obs;
>
>   List<BottomMenuModel> bottomMenuList = [
>     BottomMenuModel(
>       icon: const Icon(
>         Icons.home,
>         size: 40,
>       ),
>       title: "lbl_home".tr,
>       type: BottomBarEnum.Home,
>     ),
>     BottomMenuModel(
>       icon: const Icon(
>         Icons.credit_card,
>         size: 40,
>       ),
>       title: "lbl_mi_valliu".tr,
>       type: BottomBarEnum.Mivalliu,
>     ),
>     BottomMenuModel(
>       icon: const Icon(
>         Icons.add_circle,
>         size: 40,
>       ),
>       title: "lbl_m_s".tr,
>       type: BottomBarEnum.Ms,
>     ),
>     BottomMenuModel(
>       icon: const Icon(
>         Icons.help,
>         size: 40,
>       ),
>       title: "lbl_ayuda".tr,
>       type: BottomBarEnum.Ayuda,
>     )
>   ];
>
>   Function(BottomBarEnum)? onChanged;
>
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     return Container(
>       decoration: BoxDecoration(
>         color: ColorConstant.whiteA700,
>         border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.shade400),
>       ),
>       child: BottomNavigationBar(
>         showSelectedLabels: false,
>         showUnselectedLabels: false,
>         elevation: 0,
>         currentIndex: selectedIndex.value,
>         type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
>         items: List.generate(bottomMenuList.length, (index) {
>           if (bottomMenuList[index].isCircle) {
>             return BottomNavigationBarItem(
>               icon: bottomMenuList[index].icon,
>               label: '',
>             );
>           }
>           return BottomNavigationBarItem(
>             icon: Column(
>               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
>               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
>               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
>               children: [
>                 SizedBox(
>                   width: 40,
>                   height: 40,
>                   child: bottomMenuList[index].icon,
>                 ),
>                 Text(
>                   bottomMenuList[index].title ?? "",
>                   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
>                   textAlign: TextAlign.left,
>                   style: AppStyle.txtInterRegular10Gray600.copyWith(
>                     letterSpacing: 0.15,
>                     color: ColorConstant.gray600,
>                   ),
>                 ),
>               ],
>             ),
>             activeIcon: Column(
>               mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
>               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
>               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
>               children: [
>                 SizedBox(
>                   width: 40,
>                   height: 40,
>                   child: bottomMenuList[index].icon,
>                 ),
>                 Padding(
>                   padding: getPadding(
>                     top: 1,
>                   ),
>                   child: Text(
>                     bottomMenuList[index].title ?? "",
>                     overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
>                     textAlign: TextAlign.left,
>                     style: AppStyle.txtInterRegular10.copyWith(
>                       letterSpacing: 0.15,
>                       color: ColorConstant.deepPurpleA200,
>                     ),
>                   ),
>                 ),
>               ],
>             ),
>             label: '',
>           );
>         }),
>         onTap: (index) {
>           selectedIndex.value = index;
>           onChanged!(
>             bottomMenuList[index].type,
>           );
>         },
>       ),
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

El problema es que no cambia el estado de los botones conforme paso de pantalla y parece que la patalla se colocara encima de la otra, como puedo optimizar este codigo y arreglar la logica para que funcione

en el gestor de estados esta esto

```
  Rx<BottomBarEnum> type = BottomBarEnum.Home.obs;
```

asi lo llamo en cada pantalla

```
floatingActionButtonLocation:
                FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
            floatingActionButton: FloactButton(),
            bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomBar(
              onChanged: (BottomBarEnum type) {
                //controller.type.value = type;
                Get.offAndToNamed(selectScreen(type, context));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String selectScreen(BottomBarEnum type, BuildContext context) {
    switch (type) {
      case BottomBarEnum.Home:
        return screenChanhet(context, HomeScreen());
      case BottomBarEnum.Mivalliu:
        return screenChanhet(context, MiValliuScreen());
      case BottomBarEnum.Ms:
        return screenChanhet(context, MSPage());
      case BottomBarEnum.Ayuda:
        return screenChanhet(context, AyudaOneScreen());
      default:
        return screenChanhet(context, HomeScreen());
    }
  }
```

ayuda y gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías implementar un pageview y controlarlo con los tab de tu CustomBottomBar y hacer que cambie de vista pero si quieres hacer que CustomBottomBar te lleve a otra pagina lo haria asi, solo que usare flutter_bloc asi puedas darte una idea

1- función para solucionar esto: parece que la patalla se colocara encima de la otra.

```
Route navegarMapaFadeIn(BuildContext context, Widget page) {
return PageRouteBuilder(
  pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => page,
  transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
  transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, _, child) => FadeTransition(
      opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
          CurvedAnimation(parent: animation, curve: Curves.easeOut)),
      child: child));
}
```

2- manejador de estado

```
part of 'tab_bloc.dart';

class TabState extends Equatable {
 final int _page;

 const TabState({ required int page }) : _page = page;

 int get curretPage => _page;

 factory TabState.init() => const TabState(page: 0);

 TabState copyWith({ int? page }) => TabState(page: page ?? _page );

 @override
 List<Object> get props => [_page];
}

part of 'tab_bloc.dart';

abstract class TabEvent extends Equatable {
 const TabEvent();

 @override
 List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ChangePage extends TabEvent {
 final int page;

 const ChangePage(this.page);
}


import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

part 'tab_event.dart';
part 'tab_state.dart';

class TabBloc extends Bloc<TabEvent, TabState> {
  TabBloc() : super(TabState.init()) {

   on<ChangePage>((event, emit) => _changePage(event,emit));

   }

 _changePage(ChangePage event, Emitter<TabState> emit) => 
    emit(state.copyWith(page: event.page));
}
```

3- CustomBottomBar

```
class CustomButtomBar extends StatelessWidget {
 const CustomButtomBar({super.key});


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return RepositoryProvider(
    create: (context) => TabBloc(),
     child: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (value) {
          switch (value) {
           case 0:
            if(value != context.read<TabBloc>().state.curretPage) {
              
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(navegarMapaFadeIn(context, const MyHomePage(title: 'HOME')));
            }
            break;
          case 1:
            if(value != context.read<TabBloc>().state.curretPage) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(navegarMapaFadeIn(context, const CreditoPage(title: 'CREDITO')));
            }
            break;
          case 2:
            if(value != context.read<TabBloc>().state.curretPage) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(navegarMapaFadeIn(context, const AgregarPage(title: 'AGREGAR')));
            }
            break;
          case 3:
            if(value != context.read<TabBloc>().state.curretPage) {
              Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(navegarMapaFadeIn(context, const AyudaPage(title: 'AYUDA')));
            }
            break;
          default:
        }
        context.read<TabBloc>().add(ChangePage(value));

      },
      currentIndex: context.read<TabBloc>().state.curretPage,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.black26,
      items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'HOME',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.credit_card),
            label: 'CREDITO',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
            label: 'AGREGAR',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.help),
            label: 'AYUDA',
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
      ]),
);
 }
}
```

4- main

```
void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
 }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocProvider(
   create: (context) => TabBloc(),
   child: MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: const MyHomePage(title: 'HOME'),
   ),
 );
 }
}
```

Espero que te sirva de guía, saludos.